# coarse moduli space $X(2)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, moduli-spaces

Let $\mathfrak{M}(2)$ be the algebraic stack over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ which classifies the elliptic curves with the $\Gamma(2)$ level structure and let $M(2)$ be its coarse moduli space. Is there an isomorphism between $M(2)$ and $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly, you need to compactify $M(2)$ to get $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]}$. Once you do, the answers to your question here:

[Modular curve X(2)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251200/modular-curve-x2#comment617833_251200)

imply that $\overline{M(2)}_{\mathbb{Q}}\cong\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand by general nonsense, $\overline{M(2)}$ is a smooth scheme over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, and hence all fibers are geometrically of genus 0.

Now, to prove that it's actually $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]}$, I believe it should suffice to produce enough distinct sections on $\overline{M(2)}$ (I think 3 should be enough, though maybe in this case 1 is enough?)

To do this, it suffices to look at the 3 cusps, which correspond via the Deligne-Rapoport compactification to the three nonisomorphic $\Gamma(2)$-structures on a Neron 2-gon. These three $\Gamma(2)$-structures are defined over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, and are not geometrically isomorphic over any prime $p\ne 2$, and hence the three cuspidal sections do not intersect over any prime $p\ne 2$. This shows that all fibers of $\overline{M(2)}$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$ over the residue field, and my intuition is that the existence of these three sections serve to "rigidify the deformation problem" (or something) to guarantee that the surface is indeed just $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}[1/2]}$ (I would be grateful if someone could elaborate on this)

Remark: Note that we can always produce a non-cuspidal section, namely, the elliptic curve
$$E : y^2 = x^3-x$$
which has discriminant $\Delta = 64$, and hence defines an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, together with the points $(0,0),(1,0)$ which define a $\Gamma(2)$-structure on $E$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$. This section together with the 3 cuspidal sections never intersect over any prime $p\ne 2$, and indeed forms a maximal set of nonintersecting sections, since at $p = 3$, $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_3}$ only has four $\mathbb{F}_3$-rational points!

Appendix: A Neron $n$-gon is a chain of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$'s, where $0$ in one copy is glued to $\infty$ in the next copy. A Neron 1-gon is just a nodal cubic. The smooth locus of an $n$-gon is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and is equipped with the obvious group structure, where $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is viewed as a constant group scheme. It's $n$-torsion is thus just $\mu_n\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. For $n = 2$, we find that over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, its 2-torsion is $\mu_2\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is completely decomposed as a finite etale group scheme over $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, and thus admits three nonisomorphic bases (ie, three nonisomorphic $\Gamma(2)$-structures), each of which corresponds to a cuspidal section of $\overline{M(2)}$.

Comment: I forget to add in my question '' 2-nero polygone ''. In your answer you said that smooth implies irreducible, I think that is not true because we need to know that our space is connected and which is true by a result of Zariski  since $(X(2)(\mathbb{C})$ is connected. Exemple $X(3)(\mathbb{C})$ is not connected but $X(3)$ is smooth.

Comment: @AdelBETINA Where did I say "smooth implies irreducible"? Anyway, $X(2)$ is certainly connected.

Comment: I want to say how to prove that the fibre is reduced at $2$?

Comment: Since in your answer you think that the normalisation of $X(2)$ over the j-line is $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: @AdelBETINA I don't think that's even true, at least if you take the Katz-Mazur regular model of $M(2)$.

Comment: @AdelBETINA Sorry that was a typo. In my answer I never look at the fiber over 2. In any case your question doesn't ask about the fiber over 2.

Comment: @AdelBETINA Though incidentally, the normalization of the projective $j$-line over $\mathbb{Z}$ inside the function field of $X(2)$ may well (for stupid reasons) just be $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}$, but if this is true, then this normalization is probably not the right model to look at from a moduli-theoretic point of view.

Comment: if you take $X(2)$ as the normalisation over the $j$-line, it will be a Cohen-Macaulay scheme and since it is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$, it will be Cohen-Macaulay over $\mathbb{Z}$. If we can proof that the fiber at $2$ is generically reduced, it will be reduced.

Comment: But juste one thing, how we can proof that the genus of any fibre is zero (we know that the genus is locally constant)? it is easy to see that X(2) is irreducible ?

Comment: @AdelBETINA arithmetic genus is invariant in flat families. Since our family is moreover smooth, arithmetic genus = geometric genus.

Comment: it is locally constant in a proper flat family  (EGA III)  but we need the irreducibility to say that is constant ( we need properness), we know that $X(2)$ is proper.

Comment: @AdelBETINA the family is proper here, and the base is irreducible. What's the problem?

Comment: @AdelBETINA It's obviously connected. It's also smooth over a regular scheme, so it's regular, hence normal, hence irreducible.

Comment: @AdelBETINA If you don't mind, may I ask what you're working on?

Comment: I want to understand the geometry of the $p$-adic rigid curve associated to $X(\Gamma_0(p) \cap \Gamma(N)$ and its formal model.